# Strange issue when unit testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, testing, phpunit

I had experienced very strange problem while doing unit testing for a PHP application using CakePHP framework. The problem is that an unit test that test simple function from my controller fails. **BUT** the strange thing is that the same test passes for some other developer that I am working with and for some other it doesn't. I am using the XAMPP stack on Windows machine and tried to reinstall everything (incl. PHP and Apache server) and still doesn't work. Same with another developer that reinstalled the whole OS (Mac OS there).

> phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="true"
     colors="false"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     mapTestClassNameToCoveredClassName="false"
     strict="false"
     verbose="false"
     bootstrap="./CakePHP/tests/bootstrap.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="phpcs">
            <file>./CakePHP/tests/CakePHPStandardTest.php</file>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

I think it might be some misconfiguration somewhere, so if you have any better suggestions please share.

Comment: Without code or error messages, how? Apparently your test depends on certain server settings - which is why for some it passes, for some it doesn't.

Comment: you have not provided us with any code, have not provided us with any real example, have gone with your assumption, and well, what do you expect from us?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check configuration of PHPUnit.
Maybe these options have different values:

```
convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
```